# Java can't compile in terminal because of external libraries

Tags: java, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, terminal, compilation

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 trying to run my code in the terminal.
The program works without problems in VScode, also when running multiple instances.
The program is consisted of six class files.

The trouble occurs when I try and run it with terminal. When compiling the java file
with `javac` it shows errors at places where I use the external libraries.

If I compile it with VScode and run the class file in terminal, I get the following error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

This is causing me problems since I'm also supposed to dockerize the program.

Comment: Typically VS Code at the top of the program output will include how it compiled the program. Can you include that here? Depending on your project setup, VS Code may have made a jar file that you would run (instead of the `.class` files).

Comment: This is the output I get: /usr/bin/env /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java @/tmp/cp_n2vvkvo9bob1x4gtes87dlwf.argfile Peer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generally indicates that the class path with which you're compiling your program does not include the correct paths to your libraries. Assuming your libraries are jar files, your `javac` command should look something like this:

```
javac -cp libs/lib1.jar:libs/lib2.jar srcs/*.java
```

where `libs/` is the relative path to your libraries and `srcs/` is the relative path to your own java files.

And when you run the program, make sure your class path includes both the locations of your libraries and the location of your class files (which in this case would be the current directory):

```
java -cp .:libs/lib1.jar:libs/lib2.jar <MainClass>
```

Comment: Hi there, this seems to have helped, now the only problem is it's missing the other classes. Should I add them to the command line after the main class?

Comment: Update: I managed to compile it, but when running the program, it says the main class can't be found.

Comment: Update: The way you showed works, all I had to do is provide the complete class path for the main class. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code in your `setting.json` file `"java.project.outputPath": "bin"`,
This will be the `.class` file generated by VS Code in the `bin` folder of the same directory when running the Java code.

You can use the java command after entering the file directory with the `cd` command.

Comment: This is the setting I have by default. VS Code puts the compiled ```.class``` files there, but if I compile the ```.java``` files with terminal, the class files will end up in the same directory then.